# Schemeless URL valid in HTTP?

Tags: html, http, url-scheme

Are schemeless urls like

```
//blog.flowl.info/
```

valid in HTTP (rfc?), like in plain HTTP **Requests** and **Responses**, or are they only valid in HTML attributes and content ?

```
HTTP/1.1 302 - Moved
Location: //blog.flowl.info

GET //blog.flowl.info
```

**Update:**

I have two contradictionary answers now. Which is correct?

Sidequestion: 
Why does the browser even resolve those to:

```
//blog.flowl.info/ 
->
http://blog.flowl.info/
```

instead of:

```
//blog.flowl.info/
->
http://blog.flowl.info///blog.flowl.info/
```

Comment: Quentin's answer cites RFC 2616. Julian Reschke's cites RFC 7231, which replaced 2616, so Julian's answer is correct. This is one of the things that changed between the two specifications (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#changes.from.rfc.2616)

Comment: Had a little trouble finding this; here are some keywords *(is the main search looking at comments?)*: location header, no scheme, double slash syntax, only authority, only host, no protocol, relative reference, relative URI, relative URL, non absolute URL, https, redirection.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37412756

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are valid in the Location header field (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.location).

They are not valid in the request line of an HTTP request.

The browser resolves it this way because this is how relative reference resolution works (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#reference-resolution).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand protocol/scheme is a mandatory part of an URL and is used by server and intermediate proxies/gateways etc to infer how to handle communication on top of plain TCP/IP. If you are not using http/https but some other well known or even custom protocol, you will have to specify it.

Browser was created for browsing html pages served over HTTP protocol. Hence if you don't specify scheme it automatically defaults it as http. There is also concept of absolute v/s relative URL that you will need to look into how subsequent URLs are resolved by browser.