# Fully-qualified urls in HTTP Location header. Why it is important?

Tags: http, url, header, location, fully-qualified-naming

So I've got some warnings from Fiddler that I have bad urls in HTTP Location header and they are should be fully-qualified. Why it's so important and what issues that can lead to?

Comment: The formal definition for a location header simply defines the payload to be an absolute URL. So using something relative violates the protocol definition: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html That does not mean that things must break for relative targets, but you have absolutely no guarantee that a client reacts the way you expect.

Comment: @arkascha you are referring to an outdated spec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old standard for HTTP/1.1 ([RFC 2616 § 14.30](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30)) required that `Location` be an absolute URI.

Implementation experience showed that this was not important, and many implementations allowed relative URIs in `Location`, so the current standard ([RFC 7231 § 7.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)) allows relative URIs.